# Good (PHP Programming Practice)

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, standards

I'm pretty new to web development and an trying to build a set of rules for good programming practice before I start learning bad habits. Therefore I wanted to ask you all for any wise words on what practices you would recommend to a newbie to adopt early on both in terms of code re-usability and readability for others. Below I've shared a few 'rules' that I've picked up so far for myself (please feel free to correct/update if any of these are 'old' or irrelevant):

**Double vs single quotes:**

- Echo statements with double quotes so that variables can be resolved
  in-line (including html tags and carriage return/tabs - but not
  functions)
- Html tag id/name/value values in single quotes

**Indenting:**

- Nesting with indents
- When using `echo` to output HTML code, use `\n` for carriage return and
  `\t` for a tab (when in double quotes - on linux server)

**Classes and Functions:**

- Store in a separate file(s) (eg `include('includes/functions.php')`) to
  store all classes/functions to be used on the website
- Keep below structure so that lines can be cut/pasted in their
  entirety

  ```
  class name {
      classproperty='value';

      function name ($a) {
          methodproperty='value';
      }
  }
  ```

**External scripts:**

- Do not put them directly in the header (it slows the page loading)
- Do not put them in the footer. Even though the content will be
  loaded, it delays the load status
- Combine all slow scripts into one external file and load with the
  below code (replacing `defer.js` with your script file):

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "defer.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  }
  if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
  else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
  </script>
  ```

**AJAX/POST/GET:**

- Use AJAX when REQUESTING data from the server
- Use POST/GET when SUBMITTING data to the server

**Databases:**

- PDO connections are more versatile than mysqli (procedural or object
  orientated) as can handle multiple types of databases
- Use `Prepare()` and `BindParam()`/`BindValue()` to ensure protection against
  code insertion

**PHP miscellaneous:**

- Use `require_once()` and `include_once()` to save unnecessary loading
  (unless using it to reconnect to a database);
- Define substrings individually and then insert into a compiled
  variable to echo out, eg:

  ```
  foreach($users as $user) {
      $id=$user['id'];
      $value=$user['name'];
      $selected=($user['name']=$_POST['username'] ? 'SELECTED' : '');
      echo "<option id='$id' $selected >$value</option>";
  }
  ```

Happy coding!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a wikipedia for things like this. There is no question in your 'question'.

Comment: I could.... google all this for you.

Comment: it is a question... and a pretty good one. The problem is, that there is no universally accepted answer... Just opinions... P.S: I up voted your question, because I like your research ;)

Comment: Yeah good point guys... I've found the members on stackoverflow to really know their stuff so it was my first thought to ask the community to share their insights on good standards to follow

Comment: If you are pretty new to web development do not trying to build a set of rules for good programming practice. There are also a lot of. Try to search for coding standard, design pattern. After you pick up one, always be consistent. I do not know what you are trying to do in that example code in classes secrtion, but that has a lot of syntax error.

Comment: @lolka_bolka all his code is "good practice" standard code, probably copy-paste form some tutorial... but nonetheless it's good to have a question like this on SO... reminds us of coding standards... I for one hate it when people put the curly braces a line below the class definition :))

Comment: @lolka_bolka I've changed (hopefully correctly) the classes section of code...thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Bendy it does not matter... it's just a simple example it's not like someone will actually take that code and use it via copy-paste :)) (I hope)

Comment: [PHP: The Right Way](http://phptherightway.com/) could help you.

Comment: @AresDraguna lol yes, but I thought if I correct it then I'd at least know the answer as otherwise someone would point it out again ;)

Comment: @DavidePastore ...a whole site on it! Thanks!

Comment: @Bendy again, there is no Universal correct and accepted answer for you question. We are individuals, and it's normal that we code differently :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to say anything specific about good programming practice with PHP since that subject is very general but I'll share my opinion on your 'good programming practices'.

**Double vs single quotes:**

> - Echo statements with double quotes so that variables can be resolved in-line (including html tags and carriage return/tabs - but not functions)

- There's no telling whether resolving variables in echo statements is good programming practice. There's no wrong way of doing it. Do what you find suits your eyes best.

> - Html tag id/name/value values in single quotes

- I myself like to have them in double-quotes.

**Indenting:**

> - Nesting with indents

- Your IDE should take care of your code formatting and indentation in most cases.

**External scripts:**

- The only thing that's good practice about JavaScript is to keep your code just above the closing `<body>` tag. If you wish to be very disciplined over JavaScript I'd recommend [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) - the bible of JavaScript good programming practices.

**AJAX/POST/GET:**

> - Use AJAX when REQUESTING data from the server

- I'm not sure what you think AJAX is. You can use AJAX to retrieve *and* post data to the server. Read up on AJAX and understand it fully before forming opinions on it.

> - Use POST/GET when SUBMITTING data to the server

- There's a reason it's called `GET`. It's used for getting data from the server. Don't submit data using `GET`.

**Databases:**

> - PDO connections are more versatile than mysqli (procedural or object orientated) as can handle multiple types of databases
> - Use `Prepare()` and `BindParam()`/`BindValue()` to ensure protection against code insertion

- If you use a good PHP framework you won't need to worry about your data layer. Especially if that framework makes use of an ORM.

**PHP miscellaneous:**

> - Use `require_once()` and `include_once()` to save unnecessary loading (unless using it to reconnect to a database);

- The reason `require_once()` and `include_once()` exist is because sometimes including a script more than once can cause an error. Like when you have `define()`d variables.

> - Define substrings individually and then insert into a compiled    variable to echo out, eg:

```
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $id=$user['id'];
        $value=$user['name'];
        $selected=($user['name']=$_POST['username'] ? 'SELECTED' : '');
        echo "<option id='$id' $selected >$value</option>";
    }
```

- This is also a matter of opinion.

To wrap it up:

Don't do preemptive performance fixes. You seem like a smart person so do what you think is logical. Write readable and documented code. **Use a framework.** Cannot stress this enough. Try Laravel, Symfony, Zend. Those are the major/most popular ones. Use a good IDE. My personal favorite is PHPStorm. And last but not least, **code**. Just write code, create applications. Skill will follow naturally and with time you'll be amazed how much your programming has improved. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to comment on each point :) I have just been using notepad++ . I'm now off to look into frameworks and IDEs - thanks again!

Comment: Regarding the \n \t indenting, that probably wasn't very clear. I meant to say that I've been using it to send indents to the final HTML code so that when I went to look at the source code I still have it nicely indented to help me find where my errors are(!) ;)

Comment: @Bendy No problem. As you start to build larger applications you'll run into more complex issues and realize you're unable to work without proper debugging that's an essential feature of an IDE. I'll remove the part about `\n` and `\t`.